# Jquery conflict using legacy template - is there a way to correct it?

Tags: joomla-3.x, jquery

I have a client who is trying to follow a Udemy course which uses a template from 2014 with the Jgive component.

I have tried with different templates and the jQuery error does not appear, so it must be template related.

The code that is being flagged up is:

```
if(typeof(techjoomla)=="undefined"){var techjoomla={}}if(typeof(techjoomla.jQuery)=="undefined"){techjoomla.jQuery=jQuery.noConflict()};
```

With the error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined @ namespace.min.js:1
>        (anonymous) @ namespace.min.js:1

The error occurs on the last bit: =jQuery.noConflict()};

The page is located [here](http://mybroski.net/index.php/start) although it does require registration to view the page - please feel free to register if need be, or if the error in the code is obvious, please let me know and I'll correct it and post back.

I have updated to Joomla 3.7.2 to see if the issue fixes itself but it does not unfortunately.

Thank you in advance
Regards
D

Answer (score 1):

you need to load jQuery before the code you pasted is run, which is done automatically by most modern templates.

A quick solution is to open the template's index.php file and paste this at the beginning of the `<head>` section:

```
<head>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

if you still face errors after this it may be due to the code requiring an older jQuery, look [here](https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/#jquery) for a complete list.

An alternative and possibly easier way to achieve this is to install a plugin that will do it for you, for example jQuery easy.

Comment: Thanks Riccardo - I've tried using jQuery Easy, but the Jgive component still loads its own version of Jquery first. I have also manually added it into the Index.php of the template but it doesnt make a difference. If you have a look now, you will see the version I have added is way below the version the extension loads. Its frustrating to say the least.

Comment: It seems to be an error loading no conflict.